# Best FP idioms for AnyVals in collections

Tags: scala, functional-programming, apache-spark, scala-collections

I have a mapper function defined as such:

```
def foo(x:Int) = if (x>2) x*2
```

the type signature of this method being `Int => AnyVal`. Now if I map this function over a list of integers:

```
scala> List(-1,3,-4,0,5).map(foo)
res0: List[AnyVal] = List((), 6, (), (), 10)
```

I need a way of filtering out the `Unit`s from the `Int`s like so:

```
scala> res0.filter(_.isInstanceOf[Int]).map(_.asInstanceOf[Int])
res1: List[Int] = List(6, 10)
```

Everything seems concisely expressed until I have to do the *filter-map* on `res0` to extract the values I care about. I could use *matchers* or an *if-else* in `foo` to always ensure I return an `Int` but I'd still need to filter the unwanted values resulting from the map operation.

Can any of the well-seasoned Scala developers reading this provide some additional insight into what's good or bad about this approach especially as my collection grows large (e.g. maybe this collection is a distributed Spark `RDD`)? Are there more idiomatic ways of doing this functionally?

Comment: I may do something like List(-1,3,-4,0,5).filter(_ > 2).map(_*2)

Comment: The question is really about `Any` because the same question would arise for, say, a function that returns a `Foobar` or `Unit`; the right way is always by using a `PartialFunction` or a function that returns `Opiton[T]` — you should always make sure the return type of your functions isn't (inferred to be) a supertype of 2 or more types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case I suggest you to use collect with PartialFunction, if you need to drop all ints that are smaller than 2

```
  val foo: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
    case x if x > 2 => x*2
  }

  println(List(-1,3,-4,0,5).collect(foo))
```

Your original foo has type Int => AnyVal, because scalac transforms it in something like

```
def foo(x: Int) = if (x > 2) x*2 else () // () === Unit
```

and common super type for Int and Unit is AnyVal

Comment: should be a `val` not a `def` — currently you're generating a new PF each time `foo` is called.

Comment: This answer isn't incorrect, but it's not really as helpful as it could be—it gives a better solution but doesn't address why the OP is getting `AnyVal` in the first place, etc. I wish people would slow down a bit and show their work—this isn't a race.